# Check if a html table contains a row with "No data"

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a table with might have no content. When I click a button, I want to populate it. But if it contains this:

```
  .............
  tbody#my_table
    tr
      td{colspan: 5} No data
```

I want to empty it first before appending rows to it.

What's an easy and reliable way to determine if a table contains or not data? Or rather a row with "No data"

Comment: Please [create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0):

I hope what you want to do is find out cells that have their content as "No Data". That's what I think you mean by

> What's an easy and reliable way to determine if a table contains or not data? Or rather a row with "No data"

To

> want to empty it first before appending rows to it.

You can do something like this (using lodash/underscore):

```
_.each(document.getElementById("my_table").rows, row => {
  _.each(row.cells, cell => {
    if (cell.innerHTML === 'No Data') {
      cell.innerHTML = '';
    }
  });
});
```

But, yeah. As **Alan Larimer** pointed out, try presenting a *Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable* problem.